# ValidationMessageFor readonly property, or one ValidationMessageFor two properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I have a class that contains

```
[Required]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[Required]
public string LastName { get; set; }

public string FullName {
    get {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have an `Html.ValidationMessageFor` FullName, or some custom validation message that appears when either FirstName or LastName is blank?

**UPDATE**

This is what I want.

1. You leave both names blank: `Full name is required.`
2. You leave FirstName blank: `Full name is required.`
3. You leave LastName blank: `Full name is required.`

Comment: But technically you won't be using it in view I suppose to show the validation message, please add more details if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following (I hope I didn't misunderstand you):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Yo fill this up please"]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

**EDIT**

In case you have a bit more specific validation requirements you can implement the `IValidateObject` through your Model, something like:

```
public class Person : IValidatableObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The full name is required.");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Controller your ModelState would indicate if the input is invalid:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // do your stuff here ...
}
```

And of course in your view you can get the validation messages through a ValidationSummary:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, this is what I want. A) You leave both names blank: `Full name is required.` B) You leave FirstName blank: `Full name is required.` C) You leave LastName blank: `Full name is required.`

Comment: Yes, that does look like it! Now, will that replace all the other default ValidationResults, or will it just add that one to the list?

Comment: @Andrew it should just add to the list. Give it a shot.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and just believe you, as the current problem has become a moot point for this project. Still really good to know, thanks!